# Непонятное поведение слайдера

Tags: jquery

На странице сделаны [2 слайдера](http://strdv.inetech.ru):

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel)
{
    // Disable autoscrolling if the user clicks the prev or next button.
    carousel.buttonNext.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    carousel.buttonPrev.bind('click', function() {
        carousel.startAuto(0);
    });

    // Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip.
    carousel.clip.hover(function() {
        carousel.stopAuto();
    }, function() {
        carousel.startAuto();
    });
};

<!-- Первый слайдер -->

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel_1').jcarousel({
        auto: 2,
        wrap: \"circular\",
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 4,
        start: 1,
        animation: 2000,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        itemFallbackDimension: 100
    });

<!-- Второй слайдер -->

    jQuery('#mycarousel_2').jcarousel({
        auto: 2,
        wrap: \"circular\",
        scroll: 1,
        visible: 4,
        start: 3,
        animation: 2000,
        initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
        itemFallbackDimension: 100

    });
});
```

В оба слайдера подгружаются пункты из одного и того же раздела, поэтому, чтобы слайдеры не были одинаковыми, для них прописаны

- для первого start: 1
- для второго start: 3

Но слайдер может работать по-разному: иногда оба двигаются одновременно, так, как и надо. Но иногда первый двигается, второй стоит на месте, или наоборот. Или они начинают движение, но некоторое время спустя один замирает, а второй продолжает двигаться.
В чем причина и как это поправить?
Тестилось в гугл хром.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С каруселями всё ок.

Обратите внимание на комментарий:

`// Pause autoscrolling if the user moves with the cursor over the clip`

Останавливает автоскролинг, если пользователь навел мышь на слайд карусели.

Вы когда страницу загружаете, мышкой проводите, вот они и начинают двигаться по-разному.

В итоге код:

```
carousel.clip.hover(function()
{
carousel.stopAuto();
}, function() {
carousel.startAuto();
});
```

удаляем или комментируем и всё ок будет.

Comment: Да, не сообразила) Спасибо)